# How to handle class visibility/access correctly

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm designing a simple game and I'm not sure how to correctly handle the access and relations between classes. E.g:

Class Game - method Start that will initialiaze objects (fields) Player, CPUPlayer, Board.

Player/CPUPlayer contains a method "Place a pawn" but they would need to access the Board object to check for coordinates.

But they do not see the Board object. Does it mean I need to pass the Board object reference (or any other objects) in their constructor?

Comment: Yes; if you want an object, you'll need to get ahold of it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if they have a dependency on that object you need to *inject* it into them when they are created. The constructor is the right place. Later on, as you get a handle on things, you may want to look into using a DI container like [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/) or something, but for now, just receive an instance of the `Board` in their constructors.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it does indeed seem that they need a reference to a Board object. If you would like to over-engineer that, you could create a specialized interface ICoordinateCheckable, implement it in the Board, and have Player accept an instance of this interface (instead of the Board) in constructor.